# Get text from an element that is not yet in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to get the text from the element IDed "list" but this element doesnt not exist yet when the page first loads, it takes like 3 seconds to appear so if I use this code:

```
var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
console.log(lists)
```

I get an error that says TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
What can I do so I get the text once the element appears?

UPDATE

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var parentOfMyList = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
            console.log(lists)
            console.log(parentOfMyList)
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);   
});
```

DIFFERENT APPROACH

```
function fuckobserver() {
            var fuckobs = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
                $.each(mutations, function (i, mutation) {
                    var lists = document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents").textContent;
                    console.log(lists)
                    });
                });
            var parentOfMyList = document.body;
            fuckobs.observe($(parentOfMyList)[0], {childList: true, subtree: true});
        }

        if (document.body.length) {
            // body is already in the DOM
            fuckobserver();
        } else {
            // body is not in the DOM yet, add an observer to detect its addition
            new MutationObserver(function (mutations, outineObserver) {
                if (document.body.length) { // body is finally in the DOM
                    outineObserver.disconnect();
                    fuckobserver();
                }
            }).observe($(document.body)[0], {childList: true, subtree: true});
        }
```

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 1):

is `#list` in your html or is it injected using javascript? If the former is the case, you can use the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) (#1) to wait until you html is loaded. If it is injected by a javascript function you have control over, you can implement a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) (#2). If you do not have control over the javascript function (e.G. a third-party-library or an external script), you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (#3).

**#1 DOMContentLoaded**

https://caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded

This will wait for your browser to tell the script that it finished loading your HTML. Wrap your assignment and your log like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
    console.log(lists)
});
```

**#2 Callback**

With this approach, you basically pass a function that will be executed at the end of another function.

```
// add callback parameter
function createList (callback) {
   // code that creates the list element you want to log
   callback()
}

// put a function that console.logs your element into the parameter 
createList(function () {
    var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
    console.log(lists)
});
```

**#3 MutationObserver** (taken from MDN, slightly modified)

https://caniuse.com/#search=mutationobserver

MutationObserver is a relatively new API to watch for changes ('mutations') in the DOM. It will fire every time it detects a change to a specific target node.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var parentOfMyList = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            if (mutation.target.id === 'topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents') {
                // do something with your element mutation.target.id

            }
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);
```

Comment: Its javascript injected I think, I will try with each one of your methods.

Comment: If you cannot edit the script injecting the list, then you will most probably need the MutationObserver approach. You can't really implement a callback if you don't have control over the function and it won't be loaded when Document is Ready. If you need help with the implementation, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Im getting this error with the #3 method: TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.

Comment: I think the problem is that parent is not loaded yet either. Can i have body observed instead?

Comment: sure, just use `document.querySelector('body')` instead of `document.getElementById('listParent')` for your parentOfMyList

Comment: I still get the error which is weird because body is always present. Does the parent of the element has to be exactly the parent that is 1 level above or can be any?

Comment: Even weirder, if I enclose everything in "setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);" then it works...

Comment: you could try setting `subtree: true` in the config object. Then it will watch all descendands of the body. Also, console.log parentOfMyList to make sure it's a DOM-Node

Comment: I did. It points body as the parent but unless I leave "setTimeout(function(){" on it wont give me any output.

Comment: Any further suggestions please?

Comment: don't have any suggestions without seeing more code. Can you reproduce the behaviour in a fiddle and link it here please?

Comment: I cant reproduce it here but I can give you the link to the actual site if you wish.

Comment: sure go ahead! I'll see what I can do

Comment: thank you, this is the link http://saintseiyaforos.net:35555/htmlchat/123flashchat.html?init_room=1&init_user=invitado&init_lang=en first you will see a loading page with only a logo in the middle, then you will see the actual site but the code is supposed to load from the loading page.

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the whole block of text inside the example of  **#1 DOMContentLoaded**, if it still doesn't work try using `var parentOfMyList = document.body`. This is a shot in the dark though, since my browser debugger is broken somehow

Comment: I tried `parentOfMyList = document.body` but I get this error `Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.`

Comment: Wrap everything in `DOMContentLoaded` listener then and see if it works

Comment: You mean put the whole #3 inside #1?

Comment: I updated my question with the modifications to the code I think you mean. This time I get the logs right although it produces logs not once but every 5 seconds or so. Please check it out.

Comment: this just means it can't find an element with the ID `#topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents`. I will update my answer soon for an implementation which waits for exactly that element

Comment: @snksaint I updated the callback in example #3. Try using this instead vor defining the lists variable

Comment: This time I get `Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.` and no log is displayed. I think there is no object with ID listParent.

Comment: just use `document.body` again

Comment: sorry again but I get the same error and no logs are shown. If you need any additional details please let me know.

Comment: No errors but no logs are shown either. I tried a different approach based on another code I have confirmed it works within the same page but its not working here for some reason. Please look at the very bottom of my question.

Comment: should I just give it up?

Comment: I don't have much time at hand at the moment but I'll try to look into it later

Comment: Okay, no problem. I can wait. I will keep on trying meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout as follows

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
    console.log(lists);    
 }, 3000);
```

3000 --> 3secs

You can provide how much time you required.

Comment: This isn't a good solution.  You're just guessing how long it will take to load the DOM.

Comment: Actually its so simple its very nice however I just found out the element wont appear on a timer but on a user click which renders it unusable but thank you.